# Design Advice Needed For Synonyms Database

Tags: database-design

I'm planning to put together a database that can be used to query synonyms of words. The database will end up huge, so the idea is to keep things running fast.

I've been thinking about how to do this, but my database design skills are not up to scratch these days.

My initial idea was to have each word stored in one table, and then another table with a 1 to many relationship where each word can be linked to another word and that table can be queried.

The application I'm developing allows users to highlight a word, and then type in, or select some synonyms from the database for that word. The application learns from the user input so if someone highlights "car" and types in "motor" the database would be updated to link the relationship if it don't exist already.

What I don't want to happen is for a user to type in the word "shop" and link it to the word car. So I'm thinking I will need to add some sort of weight to each relationship.

Eventually the synonyms the users enter will be used so they can auto select common synonyms used with a certain word. The lower weight words will not be displayed so shop could never be a synonym of car unless it had a very high weight, and chances are nobody is going to do that.

Does the above sound right? Can you offer any suggestions or improvements?

Comment: What sort of application is this? Desktop? Web? Also, is this for general synonyms, or is it targeted to a specific domain, where there might not be commonly available tables of synonyms to use as a baseline?

Comment: I like the word to synonym table relationship.  If a word is typed instead of chosen, maybe the relationship is only added to the database if the relationship ("shop" in place of "car") is typed by more than X number of people?

Comment: It's a web application. @JohnieKarr that's what I was thinking the more it's typed, the more weight it's given until it has enough weight to appear in the list.

Answer (score 1):

What you are really looking for, from a relational DB standpoint, is a many-to-many relationship between words, with possibly some additional data on the relationship.

The relational tables would look something like:

```
WORD_TABLE
----------
id
word

RELATION_TABLE
--------------
word_1_id
word_2_1d
weight
```

The way I would build it out is to do it in a way that users can vote (up or down) various word pairs. This will give you the weights you need in a fairly simple way. You will likely also want to pre-populate it with data from a thesaurus or some other similar source to cover the known synonyms and give your users less work.

Also, another term for this sort of data structure is a weighted graph.

In general, relational databases are not particularly good at modeling a graph (they can do it, but there are better options). You may want to look into a graph database (Neo4J comes to mind) as an alternative to a relational database.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a many-to-many relationship within the entities of the same entity-set. I would have one table for all the words and another table for the relationships. The relationship table will have two foriegn keys to the word table. The  tables will be something like

```
Word (w_pk, ....)
Synonym  (fk1_to_w_pk, fk2_to_w_pk, weight)
```

When adding entries in `Synonym` you have to check

```
- fk1_to_w_pk ≠ fk2_to_w_pk
- both (fk1_to_w_pk, fk2_to_w_pk) and (fk2_to_w_pk, fk1_to_w_pk) do not already exist in Synonym
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work nicely:

```
create table suggestions (
    word varchar(255),
    suggestion varchar(255) not null,
    weight float not null default 1.0,
    primary key(word, suggestion, weight)
);
```

- When a user suggests a word, you add it to the list with the default weight.
- When another user suggests the word, you increase the weight by say 1.0.
- To generate suggestions based on words suggested at least 3 times: 
  `select suggestion from suggestions where word = ? and weight > 3 order by weight desc.`

Comment: This doesn't explain how the synonym part would work.